# PowerBI - DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

How would I create a powerBI report that shows the real sprint burndowns but connecting to the AzureDevOps environment?
Is there a downloadable .pbix template available?

Regards

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi Shayki. Thank you very much for that link. I have done those reports and they are very basic. I am looking to build something like https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/powerbi/ - unfortunately I am unable to download the visual studio team services app from Microsoft. so looking for a different avenue now. Mainly a burndown report. current views available from devops are limiting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice to have option but yet to be available. There are many workarounds that you would try

1. Embed the reports from Azure DevOps burn down in Team Site / SharePoint Online portals
2. Create Power BI reports as per the need. The step by step approach is shown in [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-sprintburndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no,you need create it your self.

[Analytics views dataset design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-dataset?view=azure-devops)

[Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)